# Call handle functions with onClick and react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to do the same thing as https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/VmmPgp?editors=1010. So I have a form and I want to redirect with parameter (parameter inside the first input).

My code is:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');

class Views_Delete_Delete extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: ''};

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Valeur : ');

    }

    render() {
        var data = this.props.data;

        return (
            <div className="delete">
                <label> 
                    Supprimer les données dun bon de travail : 
                    <input className="input_id_traitement" type="text" value={data.id_traitement} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                </label>
                <input className="btn_delete_traitement" type="submit" value="Delete" onClick="{this.handleSubmit}" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = Views_Delete_Delete;
```

I don't have any error but when I click on my button, the page is reloaded. I also tried with react-router in order to use `<Link>` but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

With button type "submit", it tries to submit the form, and default behavior of it is to navigate browser to form's `action`.

Simplest solution is to change button type from "submit" to "button":

```
<input className="btn_delete_traitement" type="button" value="Delete" onClick="console.log('test');" />
```

Event better: don't use `onClick` on the button. Instead handle form `onSubmit` event (with button type "submit").

Comment: But a weird thing that I don't understand is that when I inspect the element in my page, there is no onclick attribute

Comment: @Erlaunis There will be not attribute, onClick will create event handler with addEventListener. Is `Views_Delete_Delete` part of the form?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand, the class `Views_Delete_Delete ` return the form when I call it from my router. So when I go to `/delete`, it displays the page with this form.